How to convert message to EML file
How to convert each Microsoft.Graph.Models.Message object from emailbox to EML file using C#?

For me, I use the code bellow.
var mc = gsc.Users[primaryMail].Messages[item.Id].Content.GetAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

using (var fs = new FileStream(filepath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString() + curFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    mc?.CopyTo(fs);
}
ret = true;

Thread.Sleep(1500);


The Exchange store is what will do the conversion for you need to access the $value endpoint of the message see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-mime-message
in the Graph SDK something like
var res = await graphServiceClient.Me.Messages["{message-id}"].Content.GetAsync();
var emlContent = new StreamReader(res).ReadToEnd();

